# Python - Convert 8 bit binary number to decimal

Tags: python

```
import math

while True:
    try:
        user_bin = int(input('\nPlease enter binary number: '), 2)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please make sure your number contains digits 0-1 only.')
    else:
        print(user_bin)
```

I've just been browsing this site looking for tips on how to complete an assignment, the basics of the assignment is to have the user input an 8 bit binary number, and convert it to decimal. Or pop up an invalid input error in situations where it doesn't fit the requirements. The code above seemed interesting so I tested it and I genuinely don't understand which part of the code converts the binary to decimal. Any tips for the assignment as well as explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: `int(num, 2)` will give you a decimal number from a base 2 binary number.

Comment: as a follow up question, is there an easy way to also get it to print out a message if the number input isn't 8-bit? atm it just puts out an error if I dont use 1's or 0's.

Comment: `int(num, 2)` technically doesn't give you a decimal number from a base 2 number. It gives you an integer, which you can then print in any base (default being 10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part that converts the binary is `int`. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> if *base* is given, then x must be a string, `bytes`, or `bytearray` instance representing an integer literal in radix *base*.

This means that `int` accepts a string representing an integer, that you tell it the base of. E.g. here we give it `"11"`, and tell it this is in base `2`, so it returns the integer `3` in decimal.

```
>>> int("11", 2)
3
```

Note that when supplying the `base` argument, you have to give a string:

```
>>> int(11, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

And you can't use digits that are invalid in the given base:

```
>>> int("21", 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '21'
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, i've barely worked with the try and except functions. Would it be simple to add another ValueError for if the number inputted isn't 8-bit?

Comment: It would be pretty simple, but given that this is an assignment, I'd have you think about what an 8-bit number would look like and how you would check if your input was 8-bit.